# Listerner error on Shiro web application

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, shiro

I am trying to set up authentication on a JSP based web application running on tomcat 7. I am using Java 7. I have a MYSql db so I supposed that the easier user store is the DB itself. I am trying to follow the tutorial in the official repository but, although it seems easy to follow it is not working for me. I am not sure what I am leaving behind.

I am coding on eclipse luna. I created a Dynamic web application project and created the login.jsp and home.jsp, with plain html, just for testing. login.jsp has the form, as obtained from the documentation.

shiro-core-1.2.3.jar and shiro-web-1.2.3.jar are in the lib folder.

I have obtained and adapted the following files:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>paprest</display-name>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

shiro.ini:

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
authc.successUrl = /home.jsp

# password matcher
passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService

ds = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
ds.resourceName = jdbc/myDS
ds.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM USERS WHERE username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role_name FROM USERS_ROLES WHERE username = ?
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $passwordMatcher
jdbcRealm.dataSource=$ds
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

[urls]
/login.jsp = authc
/home.jsp = anon, authc
/logout = logout
/account/** = authc
```

jetty-env.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <New id="myDS" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>jdbc/myDS</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource">
        <Set name="driverClass">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Set>
        <Set name="jdbcUrl">jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/authzDB</Set>
        <Set name="username">root</Set>
        <Set name="password">pass</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

When I export it to a war file and try to load it into the Tomcat7 server I get the following error on the catalina.out file on the deployment process:

```
jun 02, 2015 9:54:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Error listenerStart
```

I cannot find any more information but the aplication does not get deployed. I am not sure what I am missing. Any ideas?

[UPDATED]

Tomcat logs during app deploy

```
DETALLADO: Successfully processed context [/ShiroFroga] configuration file [file:/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/context.xml]
jun 02, 2015 5:34:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
DETALLADO: "ContextConfig": Procesando "START"
jun 02, 2015 5:34:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
DETALLADO: El contexto [/ShiroFroga] analizará los ficheros web.xml y web-fragment.xml con validación:false y namespaceAware:false
jun 02, 2015 5:34:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
DETALLADO: Analizando fichero de aplicación web.xml en jndi:/localhost/ShiroFroga/WEB-INF/web.xml
jun 02, 2015 5:34:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig authenticatorConfig
DETALLADO: Configuración de un autentificador (authenticator) para el método NONE
jun 02, 2015 5:34:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
DETALLADO: Pipeline Configuration:
jun 02, 2015 5:34:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
DETALLADO:   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator/1.0
jun 02, 2015 5:34:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
DETALLADO:   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve/1.0
jun 02, 2015 5:34:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
DETALLADO: ======================
```

Comment: java 7. Forgot to say it.

Comment: do you still get the error with a fresh install of tomcat 7?

Comment: Yes. Just tried on a different machine and I get the same. Tomcat has not been configured but user definition for admin console. I see that teh war gets deployed and the folder with the content is created, but it does not start.

Comment: I have not cofigured log4j so as I understand, defaults go to catalina.out, isnt it? What I don't see is why I do not get information about any error.

Comment: might help to look here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

Comment: you need to set your logger to debug to try find exactly whats happening

Comment: Adding detailed log results to the description. I don't think there is new info, but maybe you see something I don't